# IP address dialog android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I want a dialog to appear that prompts the user to input the IP address of the server to connect to. I've tried to do it myself but when I finished the app kept closing with some error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code.

```
package com.topo.control;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private Socket socket;

final Context context = this;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5005;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.2.8";




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    


    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    toastBread("Up");
                    try {
                        String str = "jj";
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                          true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    toastBread("Stop");
                    try {
                        String str = "aa";
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                          true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btn2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    toastBread("Left");
                    try {
                        String str = "aj";
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                          true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    toastBread("Stop");
                    try {
                        String str = "aa";
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                          true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    final Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    toastBread("Right");
                    try {
                        String str = "ja";
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                          true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    toastBread("Stop");
                    try {
                        String str = "aa";
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                                          true);
                        out.println(str);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitbtn);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();





}

public void toastBread(String s){
    Toast.makeText(this, s, 0).show();
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: What's the call stack of the exception? Please post the logcat output.

Comment: You can remove all the posted code as it has nothing to do with your question. Instead post the code where you try to make an input dialog.